# Train and Test accuracy not promising on large data set for image classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have around **170K** images in training set and **27k** in validation set equally  distributed for cats and dogs . I am using below code to classify cats vs dogs . Apart from the below architect, I tried different combinations of epochs/batch size/layers

```
img_width,img_height =128,128
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)
# Initialising the CNN
classifier = Sequential()

# Step 1 - Convolution
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape, activation='relu'))

# Step 2 - Pooling
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))  # 2x2 is optimal

# Adding a second convolutional layer
classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

# Step 3 - Flattening
classifier.add(Flatten())

# Step 4 - Full connection

classifier.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(0.4))
classifier.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
classifier.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images
batch_size =128
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   shear_range=0.2,
                                   zoom_range=0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip=True,
                                   fill_mode='nearest')

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(training_set_path,
                                                 target_size=input_size,
                                                 batch_size=batch_size,
                                                 class_mode='binary',
                                                 shuffle=True)

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_set_path,
                                            target_size=input_size,
                                            batch_size=batch_size,
                                            class_mode='binary')


classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch=<170K>/batch_size,
                         epochs=128,
                         validation_data=test_set,
                         validation_steps=<27K>/batch_size,
                         use_multiprocessing=True,
                         workers=12)
```

The output does not seems promising to me. I need your suggestion/help to increase training accuracy as well as validation accuracy .

```
Epoch 78: accuracy -> 0.7592, val_accuracy -> 0.6669
Epoch 79: accuracy -> 0.7602, val_accuracy -> 0.6620
Epoch 80: accuracy -> 0.7592, val_accuracy -> 0.6579
Epoch 81: accuracy -> 0.7606, val_accuracy -> 0.6636
Epoch 82: accuracy -> 0.7583, val_accuracy -> 0.6614
Epoch 83: accuracy -> 0.7614, val_accuracy -> 0.6455
Epoch 84: accuracy -> 0.7609, val_accuracy -> 0.6573
Epoch 85: accuracy -> 0.7611, val_accuracy -> 0.6653
Epoch 86: accuracy -> 0.7600, val_accuracy -> 0.6631
Epoch 87: accuracy -> 0.7597, val_accuracy -> 0.6516
Epoch 88: accuracy -> 0.7606, val_accuracy -> 0.6661
Epoch 89: accuracy -> 0.7618, val_accuracy -> 0.6639
Epoch 90: accuracy -> 0.7608, val_accuracy -> 0.6675
Epoch 91: accuracy -> 0.7622, val_accuracy -> 0.6642
Epoch 92: accuracy -> 0.7630, val_accuracy -> 0.6621
Epoch 93: accuracy -> 0.7609, val_accuracy -> 0.6557
Epoch 94: accuracy -> 0.7630, val_accuracy -> 0.6664
Epoch 95: accuracy -> 0.7620, val_accuracy -> 0.6664
Epoch 96: accuracy -> 0.7639, val_accuracy -> 0.6646
Epoch 97: accuracy -> 0.7638, val_accuracy -> 0.6697
Epoch 98: accuracy -> 0.7634, val_accuracy -> 0.6633
Epoch 99: accuracy -> 0.7629, val_accuracy -> 0.6607
Epoch 100: accuracy -> 0.7639, val_accuracy -> 0.6588
Epoch 101: accuracy -> 0.7640, val_accuracy -> 0.6616
Epoch 102: accuracy -> 0.7641, val_accuracy -> 0.6597
Epoch 103: accuracy -> 0.7656, val_accuracy -> 0.6672
Epoch 104: accuracy -> 0.7638, val_accuracy -> 0.6650
Epoch 105: accuracy -> 0.7646, val_accuracy -> 0.6572
Epoch 106: accuracy -> 0.7648, val_accuracy -> 0.6649
Epoch 107: accuracy -> 0.7645, val_accuracy -> 0.6630
Epoch 108: accuracy -> 0.7651, val_accuracy -> 0.6537
Epoch 109: accuracy -> 0.7668, val_accuracy -> 0.6623
Epoch 110: accuracy -> 0.7659, val_accuracy -> 0.6620
Epoch 111: accuracy -> 0.7648, val_accuracy -> 0.6660
Epoch 112: accuracy -> 0.7660, val_accuracy -> 0.6621
Epoch 113: accuracy -> 0.7661, val_accuracy -> 0.6714
Epoch 114: accuracy -> 0.7661, val_accuracy -> 0.6601
Epoch 115: accuracy -> 0.7639, val_accuracy -> 0.6625
Epoch 116: accuracy -> 0.7657, val_accuracy -> 0.6676
Epoch 117: accuracy -> 0.7652, val_accuracy -> 0.6700
Epoch 118: accuracy -> 0.7669, val_accuracy -> 0.6608
Epoch 119: accuracy -> 0.7668, val_accuracy -> 0.6711
Epoch 120: accuracy -> 0.7680, val_accuracy -> 0.6718
Epoch 121: accuracy -> 0.7681, val_accuracy -> 0.6676
Epoch 122: accuracy -> 0.7666, val_accuracy -> 0.6565
Epoch 123: accuracy -> 0.7673, val_accuracy -> 0.6527
Epoch 124: accuracy -> 0.7670, val_accuracy -> 0.6548
Epoch 125: accuracy -> 0.7666, val_accuracy -> 0.6602
Epoch 126: accuracy -> 0.7671, val_accuracy -> 0.6696
Epoch 127: accuracy -> 0.7680, val_accuracy -> 0.6628
```

Need your valuable suggestion/guidance or snippet to try , please.

Comment: How about getting rid of dropout and using batch normalisation. Also have tried using tensorboard? This and many other issues like this become much simpler to understand with tensorboard

Comment: Another good idea is also to compare your architecture for others that are known to perform well on image classification tasks, like AlexNet, ResNet, or similars.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same filter number for the first, second, and third Convolutional Layers. According to my experience, it is better to increase the filter numbers with the Convolutional Layers, for example 32->64->128 and so on. Then your modal can get more features.

Answer (score 1):

@NormanZhu gave you a good tip. But there are other things you may try. Like adding `BatchNormalization` layer and use `LeakyReLU` instead of ReLU:

```
x = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=1)(inputs)
x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = LeakyReLU(x)
```

After that you can use `MaxPooling` and that may be the building block for your code. Stack few of those and then add `Dense` layer(s) and you should be good. Maybe even try lowering the dropout.

Maybe also try preprocessing images in some way, maybe you can get the accuracy to increase.